# Checking SQL Database for value

Tags: php, html, sql, database, mysqli

I am trying to use php to check my database to see if a value exists. My main goal is to use this value

```
$_GET['UDID']
```

and if it is equal to any value that is in the database it will return

```
echo 'FOUND';
```

I am using this code:

```
<?php

$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("CONNECTION FAILED: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

$udid = $_GET['UDID'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $udid);

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT udid FROM data WHERE udid = '$id'");

if($result === FALSE) {
   die("ERROR: " . mysqli_error($result));
}
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
          if($row['udid'] == $udid) {
              $results = 'Your device is already registered on our servers.';
              $results2 = 'Please click the install button below.';
              $button = 'Install';
              $buttonlink = 'https://**link here**';
          }
          else {
              $results = 'Your device is not registered on our servers';
              $results2 = 'Please click the request access button below.';
              $button = 'Request Access';
              $buttonlink = 'https://**link here**';
          }
    }
}

?>
```

But for some reason it is not working, I am sure I am over looking something. your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT udid FROM data WHERE udid = '" .$udid. "'");
```

And also, make sure to set the value from 'GET' to $udid. Should be like this:

```
$udid = $_GET['UDID'];
```

We can use mysqli_fetch_array() instead to get the result row. I also include error handling. Now your code must look like this :

```
$udid = $_GET['UDID'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $udid);

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `udid` FROM `wmaystec_WMT-SS`.`data` = '$id'");

if($result === FALSE) {
   die(mysqli_error("error message for the user")); //error handling
}
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
          echo "FOUND :" .$row['thefieldnameofUDIDfromyourDB'];
    }
}
```

Comment: $udid=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET['UDID']);

Comment: @Jixone OK.... The above code is now working but now I need it to check if it exists and if it does do something. I updated the question code.

Comment: @WillMays Did my code show you the correct results?

Comment: @Jixone Yes. It is showing the correct results now need to get the bottom working. I added it to my question code.

Comment: @WillMays Now, you just need to move that if condition inside the while loop, under the echo of found result.

Comment: @Jixone great it works thanks for all the help. Sorry it took soo long. Now is this secure enough to store passwords?

Comment: @WillMays Welcome! Glad could help. This code is secure enough from sql injection of the input from users but for password security, you can do hashing before saving them to your database. You can read about password hashing from this :(http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151964/discussion-between-will-mays-and-jixone).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first escape the string, using the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function, and then call the SQL query.

```
$udid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $udid);
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT udid FROM data WHERE udid = '$udid'");
```